# Shorthand expansion exercise from K & R C (ex 3-3)

Tags: c, strings

I have written a function to take some shorthand input and expand it into the full form, for example a-z0-9 becomes abcd...789. I added protection from buffer overflow exploits (knocks on wood), and have covered (or think I have) all and any edge cases that the user could throw at it.

Are there any ways in which my code could be improved (subjective and objective criticism welcome here)? Have I missed an edge case? are there any insecure sections of my code that might allow for a buffer overflow? Is my code written in a fairly concise and readable way?

```
// expand.c - function expand(s1, s2) takes shorthand input (i.e. a-z0-9) and expands it, placing the result in s2 (i.e. abcde...789)
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLEN 256
#define UP 1    //Included only to help improve readability 
#define DOWN -1 //Ditto

void expand(char s1[], char s2[]);

int main()
{
    char output[MAXLEN], input[MAXLEN];
    printf("Enter string to expand: ");
    fgets(input, MAXLEN + 1, stdin);
    expand(input, output);
    printf("%s\n", output);
    return 0;
}

void expand(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i, j, k, count;
    for(i = j = 0; s1[i] != '\0' && i < MAXLEN && j < MAXLEN; i++) {
        if(s1[i + 1] == '-' && s1[i + 2] != '\0') {
            if(s1[i] < s1[i + 2])
                count = UP;
            else
                count = DOWN;
            for(k = 0; s1[i] + k - count != s1[i + 2] && j < MAXLEN; k += count, j++) {
                if(s1[i - 1] == '-' && k == 0)
                    j--;
                s2[j] = s1[i] + k;
            }
            s2[j] = '\0';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are some comments regarding your code:

- Using `s1[i+2]` and `s1[i-1]` can possibly refer to memory locations outside of allocated memory
- Inside of `expand()` you use the restriction of `MAXLEN` which is not conveyed in the parameters, which should be like `char s1[MAXLEN]` (which also introduces different strange aspect of the c-language). As your code stands now you can easily call it with `char fails[2]; expand(fails, fails)`
- You should also test for null before accessing input parameters, currently you can call `expand(input, 0)` and it will happily try to do something which will fail
- You are better of to always include braces around blocks within `if-else` statements to avoid erroneous indentation errors
- Give `s1` and `s2` proper names to indicate what they are
- You'll possibly get into problems or unwanted behaviour, with input like `z-0`, `a-00--a`, `Z-0`, `--[`
- The range `a-a` will give `count = DOWN`<del>, and behave somewhat strangely</del>

Regarding the brace comment, consider the following code snippet:

```
int a = 13; int b = 5;
if (a < b)
   a = a + 10;
   if (a > b)
      a = 5;
else
   b = 6;
```

What will `a` and `b` hold now? Correct answer is `a=5, b=5`. If surrounding the blocks with braces the code would behave like you possibly read it, indicating the correct response of `a=13, b=6`. This is a constructed example, but it does happen way to often in real life that someone indents the code wrongly and strange things happen.

Here is the code example again, using starting braces on the same line, many prefer them to be on a new line. Choose a style, and stick to it.

```
int a = 13; int b = 5;
if (a < b) {
   a = a + 10;
   if (a > b) {
      a = 5;
   }
} else {
   b = 6;
}
```

Comment: I do understand your point about the braces, but the way I write code is to initially include all braces and then remove all unnecessary ones (only the unnecessary ones mind you) when it is finished, and then retest the code to check if any of it fails. EDIT: to what strange behaviour are you referring? it works as expected on my machine

Comment: Yes - it cycles through all ascii characters between '0' and 'z', just as intended

Comment: As for the a-a part, that just prints 'a', which I think is what should be expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26773/discussion-between-holroy-and-psychedelic-alex).

Answer (score 4):

## Bug 1

You input your string with:

> ```
> fgets(input, MAXLEN + 1, stdin);
> ```

but this may write past the end of your buffer, which is of size `MAXLEN`.  `fgets()` will read up to `n-1` characters but also add a null character.  In your case, this means that it may put a null character at `input[MAXLEN]`, which is out of bounds.  You should either call `fgets()` with `MAXLEN`, or make your arrays bigger by one.

## Bug 2

Also related to `fgets()`, your input string contains a newline at the end, because `fgets()` keeps the terminating newline.  You should strip the newline out, otherwise typing something like `"a-"` ends up being the input string `"a-\n"`, and it will expand the whole thing out.

So, the fixed up version would look like:

```
    fgets(input, MAXLEN, stdin);
    input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';
```

## Bug 3

From my reading of the problem statement, it seems to me that the input string may contain single characters not in a sequence.  For example, the input string `"axz"` should output `"axz"`.  If you input that string into your program, it will completely ignore the whole string, never setting anything in `output`, and you will end up printing an uninitialized string.

## Bug 4

You have a part in your loop where you try to skip the first character in a sequence if it has already been used in a previous sequence:

> ```
>             if(s1[i - 1] == '-' && k == 0)
>                 j--;
> ```

There are two things wrong with this:

1. On the first sequence, it reads `s1[-1]`.
2. If the input string is `"-a-c"`, the output will be `"bc"`, skipping the `a`.  The proper output should be `"-abc"`.  (According to the problem statement, leading and trailing dashes should be treated as literal dash characters).

## Fixed code

As I was fixing your code, I found that once I fixed Bug 3, I was able to remove the code that was involved in Bug 4.  Here is the final fixed up code:

```
void expand(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i, j, k, count;
    for(i = j = 0; s1[i] != '\0' && i < MAXLEN && j < MAXLEN; i++) {
        if(s1[i + 1] == '-' && s1[i + 2] != '\0') {
            if(s1[i] < s1[i + 2])
                count = UP;
            else
                count = DOWN;
            for(k = 0; s1[i] + k != s1[i + 2] && j < MAXLEN; k += count, j++)
                s2[j] = s1[i] + k;
            i++;
        } else {
            s2[j++] = s1[i];
        }
    }
    s2[j] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Always use braces as nasty bugs can arise if you don' t.

I mean

```
 if(s1[i - 1] == '-' && k == 0) {
```

Also remember that the braces are more common at the next line, like you already do in function definitions. Choose one style and stick to it.

---

```
        if(s1[i] < s1[i + 2])
            count = UP;
        else
            count = DOWN;
```

Use a ternary instead of the above:

```
 count = s[i] < s[i + 2] ? UP : DOWN
```

It is more readable in my opinion.

---

Use C99 and declare loop variables inside the loop declaration

```
for (int i = 1; ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I like that you're using array indices instead of pointers. It's much easier to understand what's going on, in my opinion.

I'd rename the function arguments and use `const` to make it clear what's modified and what's not:

```
void expand (const char pattern[], char result[])
```

That way when I look at the function prototype in a header a year from now, I don't have to think, "Gee, which one is the input and which is the output?".

I notice there's no error handling. That's probably fine for an exercise, but if this were production code, you'd want to verify that the pattern was a valid pattern, for example.

You access `s[ i + 1 ]` quite a bit in the loop. It would be easier to read if it were put into a variable with a name. Something like:

```
const char nextPatternChar = s[ i + 1 ];
if (nextPatternChar != '-' && s [ i + 2 ] != '\0')
{
    const char patternStart = nextPatternChar;
    const char patternEnd = s [ i + 2 ]; // NOTE: Don't do this outside the if or you could get an illegal access!
    if (patternStart < patternEnd)
    {
        count = UP;
    }
    else
    {
        count = DOWN;
    }

    for(k = 0; patternStart + k - count != patternEnd && j < MAXLEN; k += count, j++) {
        if(s1[i - 1] == '-' && k == 0)
            j--;
        s2[j] = patternStart + k;
    }
    s2[j] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would write it as a "state machine", and only pass through the string once, setting flags based on characters processed.
EDIT:
Here is a simple program to strip extra spaces and tabs from a file. I pulled this out of a bigger program that strips comments and other things. It filters the input from stdin one character at a time, outputting the character, or not, based on the current flags. Flags are all cleared upon any non-whitespace character, resetting the state.

```
/*
Strip.c (c) 2015 SiteNook
Remove extraneous whitespace.
Prints stdin to stdout (usually file to screen)
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ON  1
#define OFF 0

// prototypes
void output (char);

int main (void) {

    char    ch;
    int F_newline=OFF, F_space=OFF, F_tab=OFF;  // Flags for special characters

    do {
        ch = getc (stdin);
        switch (ch)
        {
        case '\n':
            F_newline = ON;
            continue;
        case ' ':
            F_space = ON;
            continue;
        case '\t':
            F_tab = ON;
            continue;
        default:
            // keep a single newline, if one exists
            if (F_newline) 
                output ('\n');
            else
                // keep (change) all spaces and tabs to a single space
                if (F_space || F_tab)
                    output (' ');
            // reset flags
            F_newline=F_space=F_tab = OFF;
            break;
        }
        output (ch);
    } while (ch != EOF);
    return (0);
}

void output (char ch)
{
    putc (ch, stdout);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't pass tests for "-a", "z-", "a-Z", or "z-A".
The exercise tells to take leading or trailing `-` literally, meaning they should not expand to anything.

```
// Test 1: expected "-a"
Enter string to expand: -a

// Test 2: expected "z-"
Enter string to expand: z-
zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! 



// Test 3: expected "a-Z"
Enter string to expand: a-Z
a`_^]\[Z

// Test 4: expected "A-z"
Enter string to expand: A-z
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

In cases like "a-Z" or "A-z", there are not really expanding anything. Some people might think "a-Z" should print lower case a-z and upper case a-z whereas others might think it should print the literal string.